# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference in Android JSON

Tags: android, json

I am running my app and its getting an error inside the doInBackground() method.
With the error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference. Here is my code

```
Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance

        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String json_curny_rates = sh.makeServiceCall(url_currency_rates, ServiceHandler.GET);
        String json_curncy_names = sh.makeServiceCall(ulr_curency_namees, ServiceHandler.GET);


        try
        {// instantiate our json parser

            jsonObj_rates = new JSONObject(json_curny_rates);

            jsonObj_names = new JSONObject(json_curncy_names);

            s_rtes = jsonObj_rates.getJSONObject("quotes").toString();
            Log.d("s_rates ",""+s_rtes);
            s_names= jsonObj_names.getJSONObject("currencies").toString();
        }catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        add_currency_rates();
        add_country_names();

    }

}
```

I have looked at other posts on this platform but non seem to locate my exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your error shows the perfect message one of your string has null object reference.
That means some of your JSON doesn't contain string you have mentioned.

Check the JSON key you have defined Is it in your JSON or not.